# Antd: How can I add tooltip to a column header for a table

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, antd

[I want to add custom tooltip for each column headers of a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvAmC.png)

I tried is using tooltip for title but that does not trigger on whole cell area

```
{
  title: <Tooltip />
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this instead of removing cell padding and adding padding for the title so that title takes up entire space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onHeaderCell` prop and a `useState` trick:

```
const [tooltipOpen, setTooltipOpen] = useState(false)
const columns = [{
  title: <Tooltip open={tooltipOpen}> colum title </tooltip>,
  onHeaderCell: handleOnHeaderCell
  ...
}]

function handleOnHeaderCell() {
  return {
    onMouseEnter: () => {
      console.log('mouse enter')
      setTooltipOpen(() => true)
    },
    onMouseLeave: () => {
      console.log('mouse leave')
      setTooltipOpen(() => false)
    }
  }
}
```

Now when your mouse hover your title cell tooltip will popup.
You can find a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-il29kc?file=demo.tsx).